# C++ Accessing variables in a function in one class from a different class

Tags: class, oop, c++11, constructor, member-functions

I'm trying to code a program with multiple classes such the one of the class reads the variables from a text file and the other classes use these variables for further processing.
The problem I'm facing is that I'm having trouble passing the variables from one class to another class, I did try "friend" class and also tried to use constructors but failed
to get the desired output.
The best I could do was
suppose I have class 1 and class 2, and I have a variable "A=10" declared and initialised in class 1, with the help of constructor I inherit it in class 2;
when I print it in class 1, it gives a correct output as 10 but when I print it in class 2 it gives an output as 293e30 (address location)
Please guide me on how to this.

```
Class1
{
public:
    membfunc()
    {
        int A;
        A = 10;
    }
}

Class2
{
public:
    membfunc2()
    {
        int B;
        B = A + 10;
    }
    membfunc3()
    {
        int C, D;
        C = A + 10;
        D = B + C;
    }
}
```

If i print variables, i expect to get 
`A = 10`, `B = 20`, `C = 20`, `D = 40`
But what I get is
`A = 10`, `B=(252e30) + 10`

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem was that you were defining local variables in your member functions, instead of creating member variables of a class object.

Here is some code based on your sample to demonstrate how member variables work:

```
class Class1
{
public:
    int A;

    void membfunc()
    {
        A=10;
    }

};

class Class2
{
public:
     int B;
     int C;
     int D;

     void membfunc2(Class1& class1Object)
     {
        B = class1Object.A + 10;
     }
     void membfunc3(Class1& class1Object)
     {
        C = class1Object.A + 10;
        D = B + C;
     }
};
```

(Full code sample here: http://ideone.com/cwZ6DM.)

You can learn more about member variables (properties and fields) here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/.

Comment: Hi Sesh Sadasivam, thank you for the help. My core program has around 30 variables read/declared in class 1, should i follow the same method to pass all 30 variables one by one? Im from mechanical background and doing some computational work using C++.